# How do I use "drush qd"?

Tags: 8, drush

In Drupal 7, I use `drush qd -y` and `php -S localhost:8000` almost weekly to get a fresh development copy of Drupal 7 to build modules or test modules before I put them into our actual development boxes.

I'm looking at Drupal 8 without much prior knowledge. Can I still use `drush qd` as I do with in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drush qd` still works fine with Drupal 8, provided that you are using the 8.x or `master` branch of Drush. In fact, I just used the latest Drush to download, install and open Drupal 8.1.1, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Can I easily switch out drush versions by `composer glboal require drush/drush 7.*` or  `composer global require drush/drush 8.*`? I'm trying to test across both 8 and 7. (This may be another full question). Thanks. Correct Answer and Upvtote.

Comment: Drush 8 supports Drupal 6, 7 and 8, so there is no need to switch Drush versions when using different versions of Drupal.